# User account got "reset" by way of the 1709 creating a new users folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1709

At 1703, my `C:\Users\` contained `Vegard`.

To this day, that much is apparent from `C:\Windows.old\Users\`:

[image]

After 1709, `C:\Users\` contains `AdminVegard` as well as `Vegard`:

[image]

(The folder isn't really 0 bytes, I took the screenshot from (the now restored) original profile. Do note the creation date, though.)

I only have 1 account to log in with, which uses the same password I was able to use for my original profile. However, all the `Desktop`, `My Documents` etc. now point towards `AdminVegard` instead of `Vegard`, and as a result, I'm locked out of all my personalization, logins, etc.

In `netplzwiz` I find only one account, but in `lusrmgr` there's two accounts -  one for each folder. My "old" account is set as disabled, and no longer an administrator.

I just want my old profile back, with my shortcuts and familiar behaviors.

**Is the fix to this as easy as enabling my old account and setting it to admin** (and then deleting the BS-account made by 1709 update)? Or will that mess with my system in some way (like somehow deleting the customizations I have in my original profile)?

Comment: Are you sure your logging into the correct account?  You must have created the account by accident because installing the feature update cannot by itself create an account.  *Enable your account and log into the correct account*

Comment: There's only 1 account to log in to. The original account, or whatever is left of it, is disabled and seems stripped of a bunch of privileges. I'd try restoring it, but I wanted to check if anyone's has any experience with this before I go and possibly destroy the profile I'm trying to save.

Comment: No; You have performed an action unknowingly that’s placed you in this situation.  Enable the account.  Desktop and ect. is supposed to point to the current profile not a disabled profile, what you describe is normal, for the case of logging into an entirely different account.

Comment: I haven't done anything for this to happen though. My workstation is always on, and I've been away on holiday for an extended time. Everything was working fine when I left, and I come back to a completely bonkers profile. I only mentioned `Desktop` et al. because I take those as proof that the update has messed with my user accounts.

Comment: Can you just simply not reenable that account and password and make it a local admin and then try logging in with it to see if that resolves? If so, then once logged in, maybe copy back the desktop, documents, etc. data from the admin appended profile, reboot and confirm it works as expected, and then disable the admin appended account? I see absolutely no harm in doing this as I explain as long as you test and confirm before disabling the admin appended account, you should be just fine. Yes, sometimes Windows Updates will do things on some PCs it doesn't do on others though.

Comment: The `Admin`-appended account has no information I need. It was created seemingly a few hours ago by the update. But more importantly, enabling the original account worked as expected.

Comment: Strange indeed but I'm glad the logical solution works as expected by simply re-enabling the account. Be sure to disable that account if you feel all is set and back in working order.

Comment: Indeed. Added some screenshots for better explanatory power, for anyone else stumbling upon this. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: The user profile folder being in Windows.old is normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the old account (and adding ADMINISTRATORS, USERS groups) from the advanced user management console worked just fine. No data loss, no funny-business.